# Firebase collection Groupby and Count the number of unique values (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, group-by, count, google-cloud-firestore

I'm totally new to Flutter and Firebase. I need some help with Firestore collection groupby and count.

I have a list of names in a collection and what I would like to achieve is to list them by unique values and count the total for each value.

Example:

List of names:

- Adam
- Peter
- Paul
- Adam
- George
- Adam
- Paul

My collection/result should return something like below with unique name and the total count for each value assigned to a variable.

- Adam [3]
- George [1]
- Paul [2]
- Peter [1]

How can I achieve this in Flutter with Firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can count names by fetching data with a query and then distinguish them using map like below code.

```
var map = Map();

_countNames() {
Firestore.instance
    .collection("collectionNameHere")
    .getDocuments()
    .then((snapshot) {
  snapshot.documents.map((element) {
    if (!map.containsKey(element.data['name'])) {
      map[element.data['name']] = 1;
    } else {
      map[element.data['name']] += 1;
    }
  }).toList();
 });
}

print(map);
```

Comment: Thank you Hussnain, I'll give this a try.

Comment: I checked it out and it worked fine. Thank you. Just a question, you mean there is no groupby option at all in firebase/firestore?

Comment: I don't know about it.